# My publications are attributed to another person's Google Scholar profile - what to do about it?

Tags: google-scholar

In *Google Scholar*, my papers are listed as the publications of another person (with a similar name like me). I suppose that Google Scholar's algorithms automatically (mis)attributed my papers to them.

I myself have not set up a GS profile, but I feel uncomfortable about my papers being listed at another person's profile.

Do you have any recommendations regarding what steps I can take to undo this misattribution?

I have already tried the following, to no avail:

- Contact Google Scholar about it (three times over a period of at least one and a half years), but I received no reaction.
- Contact the library of the university at which that other person seems affiliated (as an undergraduate student) based on their e-mail domain; the library staff contacted that person twice, but likewise have not received any response by that person.
- Try to contact that person directly, but I cannot find their contact data. (Their university library is not allowed to give me that person's contact data.)

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. 1. Start by reading the Google Scholar FAQ -> https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/about.html 2. Create a Google Scholar profile.

Comment: Thank you, @Rubén. I seem unable to find the relevant FAQs. Anyway, your second suggestion of setting up one's own GS profile helped; I could attribute my own publications to my proper profile once I established it. Do you want to write it down as a proper response so that I can 'accept' it? (- - However, I would have liked to be able to de-list my publications from the 'wrong' profile _without_ me needing to register my own profile. But this seems not possible?)